# Can't receive multicasts on Windows Server 2008

Tags: .net-3.5, networking, multicast

I have the following code which works fine on my Windows 2003 server:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            UdpClient sock = new UdpClient(5353);

            IPAddress multicastIP = IPAddress.Parse("224.0.0.251");
            IPEndPoint multicastEndpoint = new IPEndPoint(multicastIP, 5353);
            sock.JoinMulticastGroup(multicastIP);

            IPEndPoint iep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);

            Console.WriteLine("Ready...");
            byte[] data = sock.Receive(ref iep);
            ...
            sock.Close();
        }
```

Yet on my Windows 2008 R2 server (running inside VMWare Workstation with a single network adapter configured as NAT) my application doesn't receive any packets.

If I run wireshark, it shows that the packets are being delivered to the machine (they look correct and they have the right multicast IP and port) but the application layer doesn't receive anyting (it blocks forever in .Receive)

Am I missing something?

Comment: Wanted to add - the code also works fine on Win2008 when the packet is being sent from the local machine (both sender and receiver on same machine). It just doesn't work when it's sent from an outside machine on the internal network (192.x.x.x), even though Wireshark shows the packet as arriving (so i doubt VMWare is at fault). When sent from the inside machine, it's sent via the interface IP, not the loopback IP..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have gotten it to work, although I'm not sure what the problem was. It may have been an incorrect firewall configuration on the machine (I am trying to get this application to be firewall friendly) but that is beyond the scope of this thread.